# Content replacement from external website

Tags: jquery, ajax, external

So I am pretty new to jQuery and Javascript in Gen. I like the simple load() functionality that JQuery uses.  My question:  Is it possible to load content from an external website using the load() function?

```
$(#placeholder).load("http://wwww.facebook.com/someuser");
```

tring to sync content on a specific facebook page that will be loaded into #placeholder div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no you can't, for security reasons.

There are a couple of options:

1. Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) - this requires the server support returning data in that format.
2. Use an `<iframe>` to simulate the effect you're after
3. Use a proxy on your server - e.g. a PHP script you pass a URL to which returns the content of that URL. Because your server is making the request, not the client, you won't be "logged in" to the external site.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You can create a service on your website that pulls content from external sources and load from that. It's painful and roundabout, but it's the only way to achieve what you're asking. This is an [implementation in PHP](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) (which remember runs on the server) to fake the cross-site ajax.