# loading url via jquery is not working?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;" class="iframely-widget-container">
<script>$("#My-page").load("http://www.flipbeets.com/display-embed-code/ZG9sY2VnYWJiYW5h/OTAwcHg=/OTAwcHg=/MQ==/MQ==/MQ==");</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

iam trying to load flipbeets.com url via jquery into a div but it is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Content replacement from external website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639988/content-replacement-from-external-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
<div id="My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;" class="iframely-widget-container">
</div>
<script>
$( "#My-page" ).html('<object data=http://www.flipbeets.com/display-embed-code/ZG9sY2VnYWJiYW5h/OTAwcHg=/OTAwcHg=/MQ==/MQ==/MQ=="/>');       

</script>
```

Comment: is it possible to load url inside a div  through jquery without using iframe , object ,embed html tags ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iframe` instead of `div` to load your external website content.

```
 <iframe id="My-page"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#My-page").attr("src","http://www.flipbeets.com/display-embed-code/ZG9sY2VnYWJiYW5h/OTAwcHg=/OTAwcHg=/MQ==/MQ==/MQ==");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fbffqauh/1/)**

Comment: is it possible to load url inside a div  through jquery without using iframe , object ,embed html tags ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe for this like

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test page</title>

</head>
<body>

 <iframe style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;"  src="http://www.flipbeets.com/display-embed-code/ZG9sY2VnYWJiYW5h/OTAwcHg=/OTAwcHg=/MQ==/MQ==/MQ=="></iframe>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```